# ntfsfix not stopping

Tags: mount, external-hdd

I have trouble mounting my HDD, so after seeing some threads I came to know that it can be fixed using ntfsfix /dev/sdb1.

I ran it and the output is as follows

```
Mounting volume... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Checking the alternate boot sector... OK
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
NTFS partition /dev/sdb1 was processed successfully.
```

It stopped at the last line and was never ending. So I closed the terminal and tried mounting but no luck on that.

Is there any other problem with my HDD.

Comment: You haven't mentioned the size of the volume, nor the length of time you let it run before cancelling. You may not have waited long enough, and did you explore what it was doing (IO activity occurring etc) for if you did, you didn't provide any detail on what you saw and thus your conclusions (that it was doing nothing/never-ending).

Comment: Size of the volume: 1 TB;
I waited for an hour, Can you suggest some commands, so that I can execute and let you know the results.

Comment: Firstly I'd have explored the health of the drive (ie. `smartctl` or equivalent using drive electronics & not touching the platters/data area at all to assess health & consider action plan in a way that won't harm anything on drive).  Next I'd probably `fsck` or perform local checks on file-system (file system check), then I'd probably run `badblocks`.  `ntfsfix` wouldn't be my first goto at all, NTFS is a foreign *fs* so I'd consider letting windows do that check anyway... but explore health & issues before trying to fix them would be primary to me.  Did system logs provide clues of issues?